# Getting the Europa notification tone off my old phone

Tags: root-access, notifications, file-system

I'm moving from a Nexus 5X to a shiny new OnePlus 5T. I like my old Europa notification tone, but it's not on my new phone, and I couldn't find a way to find the file on my old phone without rooting the device, which I want to avoid doing.

Any idea how to get that sweet Europa tone?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to get that sweet Europa tone?

I'm not sure if you can get it off your old phone without rooting. But there is no need for that, as you can download the tone online. [Here's](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2516519&page=1) an xda thread, where the main poster posted zip files of all Nexus 5 notification tones. I imagine that the Europa tone in the 5 would be the same as in 5x.

**Instructions:**

1. Open the [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2516519&page=1)
2. In the main post, you'll see a few links. One of them will be for notification sounds. Download that one.
3. extract the file, and you will see the Europa tone.

Comment: Unfortunately that tone is not Europa from the Nexus 5X.

Comment: There is no download available at that link.

Comment: @RamRachum i just edited the post with more info

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I was able to download the sounds now, but that's still not the same Europa as the one on Nexus 5X.

Comment: I've given up at this point. I'll just another tone. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No problem. Let's hope someone comes with a better answer